# Showing the error "cannot find the module 'undefined'" when iam trying to give the location of image using props

Tags: reactjs

*I tried to pass the location of the image to app components from post component using props. But it is showing me the error "cannot find the module 'undefined'". I just want to know that how to pass a location/path of an image through the props.*

```
 {/*This is in App.js*/}

         
            <Post
              username="vishnu_ne_tha"
              caption="Nature is Beautiful"
              imageurl="./image/vishnu.jpg"    {/*This is the path of the local image*/}
            ></Post>{" "}
        
  
    
    
    {/**This is in Post.js/}
 
          

            <img
              className="post_image"
              src={require(this.props.imageurl)}  {/This is the image path called using props**/}
              alt="cant be loaded"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass image path as simple string. Try this

```
<img
  className="post_image"
  src={this.props.imageurl}  {/This is the image path called using props**/}
  alt="cant be loaded"
/>
```